# Почему добавляются неправильные значения в базу данных? PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, веб-программирование, phpmyadmin

Есть PHP код формы:

```
<?php
$host = 'Скрыто';
$user = 'Скрыто';
$pass = 'Скрыто';
$db_name = 'Скрыто';


$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);
if (!$link) {
  echo 'Не могу соединиться с БД. Код ошибки: ' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ', ошибка: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
  exit;
}

$namefilm = "namefilm";//
$ufilm = 'urlfilm'; // 
$tpage = 'textpage';//
$kpage = 'keypage';//
$gfilm = 'genre'; //
$uposter = 'urlposter';//
$dpublic = 'datepublic';//
$tfilm = 'timefilm';//
$ratingfilm = 'ratingfilm';//
$apfilm = 'apifilm';//
$akey = 'altkey';//
$voicefilm = 'voiceoverfilm';//
$qfilm = 'qualityfilm';//
$tfilminutes = 'timefilmminutes';//
$engfilm = 'engnamefilm';//
$tfilmone = 'textfilmone';//
$tfilmtwo = 'textfilmdwo';//
$tfiltree = 'textfilmtree';
$realfilmy = 'releaseyearfilm';//
$datreafilm = 'datereleasefilm';//
$cfilm = 'countryfilm';//
$afilm = 'agefilm';//
$pfilm = 'pricefilm';//
$dirfilm = 'directorfilm';//
$actsfilm = 'actorsfilm';//
$viewfilm = 'viewsfilm';//

$sql = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO `singles` (`title`, `url`, `hdescription`, `hkeywords`, `genre`, `img`, `date`, `ltime`, `rating`, `iframevideo`, `altkey`, `voiceover`, `quality`, `length`, `engname`, `d1`, `d2`, `d3`, `releaseyear`, `releasedate`, `country`, `age`, `price`, `director`, `actors`, `views`, `htitle`) VALUES ('$namefilm','$ufilm','$tpage','$kpage','$gfilm','$uposter','$dpublic','$tfilm','$ratingfilm','$apfilm','$akey','$voicefilm','$qfilm','$tfilminutes','$engfilm','$tfilmone','$tfilmone','$tfilmtwo','$realfilmy','$datreafilm','$cfilm','$afilm','$pfilm','$dirfilm','$actsfilm','$viewfilm','$namefilm')");

  if ($sql) 
  {
    header("Location: index.php");
  } 

  else 
  {
    echo '<p>Произошла ошибка.' . mysqli_error($link) . '</p>';
  }?>
```

Но при нажатии на кнопку с типом submit, отправляются те значения, что в коде формы, т.е "namefilm", а должен отправляться текст записанный в **input'e**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Форма:

```
                <div class="col-12">
                <form action="morers.php" class="form" method="post">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-7 form__content">
                            <div class="row">

                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <input type="number" class="form__input" name="idfilm" placeholder="ID" >
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <input type="text" class="form__input" name="namefilm" placeholder="Название фильма" >
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <input id="url" type="text" class="form__input" name="urlfilm" placeholder="URL страницы" >
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <textarea id="hdescription" class="form__textarea" name="textpage" placeholder="Описание страницы (Соблюдать пробелы и знаки!)" ></textarea>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <textarea id="hkeywords" class="form__textarea" name="keypage" placeholder="Ключевые слова" ></textarea>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <input type="text" class="form__input" name="genre" placeholder="Жанр (Через запятую)" >
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <input type="text" class="form__input" name="urlposter" placeholder="URL постера (Radikal/Local)" >
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <input type="date" id="datepub" class="form__input" name="datepublic" placeholder="Дата публикации" >
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                                    <input type="text" id="lenfilm" class="form__input" name="timefilm" placeholder="Время фильма (00:00:00)">
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                                    <input type="text" class="form__input" name="ratingfilm" placeholder="Рейтинг (high / middle / low)" >
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                                    <input type="text" class="form__input" name="apifilm" placeholder="API фильма" >
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                                    <input id="text"  class="form__input" name="altkey" placeholder="AltKey (Название фильма)" ></input>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                                    <input type="text" id="voiceover" class="form__input" name="voiceoverfilm" placeholder="Озвучка (По умолчанию Русская)" >
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                                    <input type="text" class="form__input" name="qualityfilm" placeholder="Качество (720/1080/4k)" >
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                                    <input type="text" class="form__input" name="timefilmminutes" placeholder="Время фильма в минутах (XXX)" >
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                                    <input type="text" class="form__input" name="engnamefilm" placeholder="Название фильма Латынь" >
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <textarea id="text"  class="form__textarea" name="textfilmone" placeholder="Описание фильма 1 строка" ></textarea>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <textarea id="text"  class="form__textarea" name="textfilmdwo" placeholder="Описание фильма 2 строка"></textarea>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <textarea id="text"  class="form__textarea" name="textfilmtree" placeholder="Описание фильма 3 строка"></textarea>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                                    <input type="text" class="form__input" name="releaseyearfilm" placeholder="Дата выхода фильма" >
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                                    <input type="text" class="form__input" name="datereleasefilm" placeholder="Дата выхода фильма" >
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                                    <input type="text" class="form__input" name="countryfilm" placeholder="Страна" >
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                                    <input type="text" class="form__input" name="agefilm" placeholder="Возраст (12+/16+/18+)" >
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                                    <input type="text" id="prfilm" class="form__input" name="pricefilm" placeholder="Стоимость (По умолчанию Бесплатно)" >
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                                    <input type="text" class="form__input" name="directorfilm" placeholder="Режиссёр" > 
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                                    <input type="text" class="form__input" name="actorsfilm" placeholder="Актеры" >
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                                    <input type="text" id="viewfil" class="form__input" name="viewsfilm" placeholder="Просмотров (0 по умолчанию)" >
                                </div>


                            </div>
                        </div>      
                        <div class="col-12">
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <button type="submit" class="form__btn">Публиковать</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

Comment: Так в вашем php-коде нет вообще никакого чтения формы...

Answer (score 0):

```
$namefilm = $_POST['namefilm'];
```

Comment: а куда это добавить? Перед чем?

Comment: в файле morers.php  вместо
 $namefilm = "namefilm";//

Comment: в базе данных теперь пустое поле место namefilm

Comment: может нужно убрать ниже код? Где query?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

if (!empty($_POST["namefilm"])) {//etc
  $namefilm = $_POST["namefilm"];
  //далее все поля

  $host = 'Скрыто';
  $user = 'Скрыто';
  $pass = 'Скрыто';
  $db_name = 'Скрыто';

  $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);
    if (!$link) {
      echo 'Не могу соединиться с БД. Код ошибки: ' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ', ошибка: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
      exit;
    }

    $sql = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO `singles` (`title`, `url`, `hdescription`, `hkeywords`, `genre`, `img`, `date`, `ltime`, `rating`, `iframevideo`, `altkey`, `voiceover`, `quality`, `length`, `engname`, `d1`, `d2`, `d3`, `releaseyear`, `releasedate`, `country`, `age`, `price`, `director`, `actors`, `views`, `htitle`) VALUES ('$namefilm','$ufilm','$tpage','$kpage','$gfilm','$uposter','$dpublic','$tfilm','$ratingfilm','$apfilm','$akey','$voicefilm','$qfilm','$tfilminutes','$engfilm','$tfilmone','$tfilmone','$tfilmtwo','$realfilmy','$datreafilm','$cfilm','$afilm','$pfilm','$dirfilm','$actsfilm','$viewfilm','$namefilm')");

    if ($sql) {
      header("Location: index.php");
    } else{
      echo '<p>Произошла ошибка.' . mysqli_error($link) . '</p>';
    }

}else{

  echo "Пусто в ".$_POST["namefilm"]."";

}
```

```
$('.form__btn').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   let namefilm = $('input[name="namefilm"]').val(),
       //etc все инпуты

   $.ajax({
        url: 'morers.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            namefilm: namefilm
            //etc все переменные
        },
        success(data) {
           //console.log(data) показать что получили 
           //document.location.href = '/index'; редирект куда после успеха
           //setTimeout(window.location.reload.bind(window.location), 2000); обновить страницу после успеха
        }
     })
})
```

К сожалению не понятно по вопросу это отправка на эту же страницу где и форма, что там с js но по тем данным что есть ответ таков.